# Input Textbox Does Not Reset in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have dropdown, checkbox, radiobox, input boxes. My reset button resets all controls except  the input textbox, the words typed does not reset. What is the problem in my code? Thanks.
App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Input from './Input';
Class App extends Component {
//get intial state
getInitialState = () => {
const initialState={
    keyword:''
 }
 return initialState;
}
state= this.getInitialState();
//reset state
onReset=()=>{
this.setState(this.getInitialState());

} 

componentDidMount(){
    this.runSearch();
}
//call API
runSearch=async(keyword)=>{
   //API CALL
});
//keywordsubmit
onKeywordSubmit=(keyword)=>{

this.setState({keyword:keyword});
this.runSearch(keyword.toUpperCase());

  }
  onReset=()=>{
  this.setState(this.getInitialState());

  } 
  render(){
    return(
        <div id="App">
        <label>Input keyword:</label><Input onChange="" value={this.state.keyword}  onSubmit={this.onKeywordSubmit} />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset Search" onClick={this.onReset}>
        </div>
    )
}

}
```

Input.js
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

```
class Input extends Component {
state={keyword:''};
//event onInputChange
onInputChange=(event)=>{
    this.setState({keyword:event.target.value});

}
//event onKeywordSubmit
onKeywordSubmit=(event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.keyword);
}

render(){
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onKeywordSubmit}>

        <input type="textbox" value={this.state.keyword} onChange={this.onInputChange}  />

        </form>
    );
}
}
export default Input;
```

Input textbox search words stays even when Reset button clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set up code to handle your form state and onChange in the parent component but you aren't using it in the child component.

Since you're passing `value`, `onChange` and `onSubmit` to your `Input` component as props you should be using them in the `Input` component via `this.props`.

Something like this should be a good start

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    //get intial state
    getInitialState = () => {
        const initialState = {
            keyword: ""
        };
        return initialState;
    };

    state = this.getInitialState();

    //reset state
    onReset = () => {
        this.setState(this.getInitialState());
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.runSearch();
    }

    handleChange({ target: { value } }) {
        this.setState({ keyword: value });
    }

    //call API
    runSearch = async (keyword) => {
        //API CALL
    });

    //keywordsubmit
    onKeywordSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.runSearch(this.state.keyword.toUpperCase());
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="App">
                <label>Input keyword:</label>
                <Input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.keyword} onSubmit={this.onKeywordSubmit} />
                <input type="reset" value="Reset Search" onClick={this.onReset} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And the input component

```
class Input extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
                <input type="textbox" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
export default Input;
```

Comment: Thanks. But the input keyword disappears when I press enter (onKeywordSubmit) and the value of the keyword doesn't get passed to the runSearch()

Comment: See edit for the fix. You don't need to set state again in the submit handler.

Comment: The input works fine but the Reset button still does not clear the input box.

Comment: You has onReset defined twice. Try removing one of them.

Comment: huh? I removed the onClick={this.onReset} and it still does not work.

Comment: In your initial question the function onReset is defined twice in the `App` component.  You should only define it once. The way you call it in `onClick` is fine. The latest edit of my response has removed the error.

Comment: oh, it was typo when I posted it. In my app, it is not defined twice. But the code doesn't work.

Comment: Any errors logged to the console or extra information you could provide? You could try settings onClick to `onClick={() => this.setState(this.getInitialState())}`

Comment: See this codepen for working example https://codepen.io/adam_th/pen/ZgQYgL

Comment: Your code works but mine doesn't. I don't see any error messages in the console. Let me check it again and report back. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I have to move the child Input component code to the App.js, remove the child and the reset button clears input textbox. Not sure what caused problem. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Right now your state logic is spread across both parent and child, and your child (`Input`) doesn't know when Reset is pressed. If you take all state out of Input (move `onInputChange` into the parent and move `e.preventDefault` to the parent's `onKeywordSubmit`), all your stateful logic will be handled in a single place, and your Input will just get the new value passed down as a prop (so it won't be concerned with Reset at all)

```
class App extends Component {
  getInitialState = () ...

  state = this.getInitialState...

  onReset = () ...

  runSearch = () ...

  //event onInputChange
  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({keyword:event.target.value});
  }

  //event onKeywordSubmit
  onKeywordSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const keyword = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ keyword });
    this.runSearch(keyword.toUpperCase());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Input onChange={this.onInputChange} keyword={this.state.keyword}  onSubmit={this.onKeywordSubmit} />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset Search" onClick={this.onReset}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```
const Input = ({ onSubmit, onChange, keyword }) => (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input type="textbox" value={keyword} onChange={onChange} />
    </form>
);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think "this" is a reserved word and can only be used in the parent component not child component when you pass down the {onSubmit, onChange, keyword}.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I missed changing those to props. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. This was the same as @adam_th 's old post. Basically convert class to function. The same issue:  input keyword disappears and keyword doesn't get passed to runSearch(). No need to reset keyword state in onKeywordSubmit function. Right now, the problem is Reset button still doesn't clear the input box.